# Has And Belongs to Many Through Save and Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are my models:

```
class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :exam_statuses,  :through => :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :examination
    belongs_to :exam_status
end

class ExamStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :examinations, :through => :categorizations
end
```

I can assign relations from the console without any problem by typing;

```
e = Examination.first
e.exam_status_ids = [1,2]
```

And also in the examinations/index.html.erb file I can list exam_statuses without any problem.

The problem is, I can't update or create any exam_status relations from **examinations/_form.html.erb** file!

I'm trying to make this with simple_form:

```
<%= f.association :exam_statuses,   as: :check_boxes, label: 'Sınavın Durumu' %>
```

Its listing all the statuses with checkboxes but not updating them.

**Logs saying:**

> "Unpermitted parameters: exam_status_ids"

And finally my controller, which is generated by "scaffold" by default, for update is:

```
  def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @examination.update(examination_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @examination, notice: 'Examination was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @examination.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: When you check a status, what do you want to happen ? You didn't specify anything that can be related to checked or validated or anything

Comment: I'm not looking for validation actually. When I try to update Examination and ExamStatus relation by checkboxes from editing page, it is not updating. Logs saying "Unpermitted parameters: exam_status_ids"

Comment: I wasn't speaking about validation either, just that I didn't know what were your checkbox for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what your logs say, you should permit the parameter, in the controller:

```
def examination_params
  params.require(:examination).permit(:exam_status_ids)
end
```

Don't forget to add other parameters in the permit call!

Then you can use it in your controller's action:

```
def update
  ...
  @examination.update_attributes! examination_params
  ...
end
```

Comment: you may should also write that permitting the parameters are done inside the controller :)

Comment: I updated the code and added my controller file. I'm not sure where your code "@examination.update_attributes! examination_params" goes in my controller.

Comment: the examiniation_paramas method should be defined in the controller, and the update method is the update action you should already have

Comment: Adding ":exam_status_ids  => []" solved my problem. It wasn't working without "=> []". Thanks @Geoffroy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `accepts_nested_attributes` in this case to get it updated.
For more details you can [**refer this article**](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through)